# Java sqlite last_insert_rowid() return 0

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a problem with `last_insert_rowid()`. It always returns 0.

```
String query = "SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS LAST FROM UGYFEL";
PreparedStatement pst1 = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet  rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs1.getString("LAST"));
pst1.execute();

//JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Adat elmentve");

pst1.close();
rs1.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `last_insert_rowid()` return valid row id(row id greater then 0) if it is invoked on the same open connection with which you performed your last insert. You can solve it via using the same connection or If you are just looking to get the `max` id from `UGYFEL`, you can get it like this

```
SELECT MAX(YOUR_ID_COL_NAME) AS LAST FROM UGYFEL
```

Answer (score 1):

So working properly. Correct?

```
                String query = "SELECT MAX(ID) AS LAST FROM UGYFEL";
                PreparedStatement pst1 = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet  rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();
                String maxId=  rs1.getString("LAST");
                //Max Table Id Convert to Integer and +1
                int intMaxId =(Integer.parseInt(maxId))+1;
                //Convert to String
                String stringMaxId = Integer.toString(intMaxId);
                tUazon.setText(stringMaxId);
                pst1.execute();

                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Adat elmentve");

                pst1.close();
                rs1.close();
```